# PHP - Multidimensional array based placeholders find and replace

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, preg-replace

I have a multidimensional array and I need to be able to replace JSON placeholders with the relevant value.
Also I need to be able to cascade the values too.

I'm probably just missing a simple thing but its been bugging me for days now.
I'd me very greatful if someone could point out a fix for me.

---

For example this is my data array:

```
$SCREEN = array(
    'z5OrfqifU8RiA' =>
    array(
        'current_status' => 'Completed',
        'email' => 'luke@test.com',
        'Messages' =>
        array(
            array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'message',
                    'messageIndex' => 0,
                    'ReceivedAt' => '17/11/2017 17:06:23',
                    'Name' => 'Luke ',
                    'Message' => 'Hello.'
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'message',
                    'messageIndex' => 1,
                    'ReceivedAt' => '17/11/2017 17:06:25',
                    'Name' => 'Luke2 ',
                    'Message' => 'Hello back.'
                )
            )
        ),
        'Message Count' => 2,
    )
);
```

---

I need to take the placeholders that represent the array values as dot notation and replace them with the correct string OR child array using a wildcard.

Here are a few examples of before and afters...

**From this:**

```
{ "Messages": "{{SCREEN.Messages}}"}
```

**To:**

```
{
    "Messages": [
        {
          "type": "message",
          "messageIndex": 0,
          "ReceivedAt": "17/11/2017 17:06:23",
          "Name": "Luke",
          "Message": "Hello."
        },{
          "type": "message",
          "messageIndex": 1,
          "ReceivedAt": "17/11/2017 17:07:06",
          "Name": "Luke2",
          "Message": "Hello back."
        }
      ]
}
```

---

**From this:**

```
{ "email": "{{SCREEN.email}}"}
```

**To:**

```
{ "email": "luke@test.com"}
```

---

**From this:**

```
{ "everything": "{{SCREEN.*}}"}
```

**To:**

```
{
  "everything": {
    "z5OrfqifU8RiA": {
      "current_status": "Completed",
      "email": "luke@test.com",
      "Messages": [
        [
          {
            "type": "message",
            "messageIndex": 0,
            "ReceivedAt": "17/11/2017 17:06:23",
            "Name": "Luke",
            "Message": "Hello."
          },
          {
            "type": "message",
            "messageIndex": 1,
            "ReceivedAt": "17/11/2017 17:07:06",
            "Name": "Luke2",
            "Message": "Hello back."
          }
        ]
      ],
      "Message Count": 2
    }
  }
}
```

---

This is the current code that works if you explicitly target a value but not for an array using a wildcard to get anything that is a child to that key.

```
$SCREEN = array(
    'z5OrfqifU8RiA' =>
    array(
        'current_status' => 'Completed',
        'email' => 'luke@test.com',
        'Messages' =>
        array(
            array(
                array(
                    'type' => 'message',
                    'messageIndex' => 0,
                    'ReceivedAt' => '17/11/2017 17:06:23',
                    'Name' => 'Luke ',
                    'Message' => 'Hello.'
                ),
                array(
                    'type' => 'message',
                    'messageIndex' => 1,
                    'ReceivedAt' => '17/11/2017 17:06:25',
                    'Name' => 'Luke2 ',
                    'Message' => 'Hello back.'
                )
            )
        ),
        'Message Count' => 2,
    )
);



$X = parseVariables('{ "everything": "{{SCREEN.*}}"}');


$Y = parseVariables('{ "email": "{{SCREEN.email}}"}');


function parseVariables($array) {
    GLOBAL $SCREEN;

    foreach(flatten($SCREEN) AS $K => $V)$array = MD_ArrayFandR("{{SCREEN.".$K."}}",$V,$array);

    return $array;
}



function flatten($array) {
    $result = array();
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value)) {
            $result = $result + flatten($value, $key . '.');
        } else {
            $result[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}


function MD_ArrayFandR($Find, $Replace,$Array){
    if (is_array($Array)){
        $ex=json_encode($Array);
        return json_decode(str_replace($Find, $Replace,$ex),true);
    } else {
        return str_replace($Find, $Replace,$Array);
    }
}


print_r($X);

print_r($Y);
```

Comment: why does `flatten` take one param but you then call it with two? a simple fix would be to use `SCREEN` as another key, i.e. add another level to the array, and not use wildcards at all. though i feel your code could be simpler :-? (not really thought it through, though)

Answer (score 0):

Write a recursive function that can descend into the structure, like:

```
function recurse($foo) {
    foreach( $foo as $key => $value ) {
        if( is_array($value) ) {
            $foo[$key] = recurse($value);
        } else if( /* $value is a placeholder */ ) {
            $foo[$key] = /* replacement */;
        }
    }
    return $foo
}
```

Comment: Hi Sammitch,
Can you explain that a bit more please?
Thank you for looking at my problem.